# sending data through a TCP socket, not received correctly

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

Hello everyone I need to convert `std::vector<uchar>` to `const char*` or send `std::vector<uchar>` over socket using `winsock2.h` in windows system.

How can I do this?

I'm compress one image:

```
std::vector<uchar> buff;//buffer for coding
std::vector<int> param(2);
param[0] = cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
param[1] = 40;//default(95) 0-100

cv::imencode(".jpeg", frame, buff, param);
```

Then:

I need to send `std::vector<uchar> buff` over socket but the the `send()` just accept `const char*`.

I have two programs, client and server and I want to send an image through a socket using a JPG buffer to be received by the server and converted back into OpenCV mat.

I already did it that way, but it didn't work:

```
int bytes = 0;

if (!imgMat.empty())                
    {
    if ((bytes = send(server, (const char*)buff.data() , buff.size(),   0)) < 0)   //if  ((bytes = send(server, (char*)imgMat.data, imageSize, 0)) < 0) 
    {
         ::cout << "Error while sending..";
         break;
    }
    ::cout << "Frame sent sucessfuly" << endl;
        ::cout << bytes << " bytes sent." << endl;
 }
else
 {
    ::cout << "Frame was empty" << endl;
    break;
 }
```

The purpose is to improve sending speed with an image that takes up less space.

Comment: *but it didn't work* -- You need to be a bit more descriptive than "it didn't work".  The code didn't compile?  It ran but didn't give the correct results?

Comment: Casting to `const char*` like you did is a way to go. Probably, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you confirm that the vector contains the data you are claiming it has *before* you called `send`?  There is nothing wrong with the code you posted -- the only thing that can go wrong is your assumption that the vector is populated with the correct data.  And if it isn't populated with the correct data, then you would have had the same results with a regular array, so the issue would have nothing to do with `std::vector`.

Comment: Good evening dear PaulMcKenzie,

The code compiled correctly and ran but but it must be sent in std::vector<uchar> buff format. How can I send vector<uchar> via socket? It's possible?

Comment: Yes, the vector has data that I am claiming,

Comment: cv::Mat imgMat = cv::imdecode(Mat(buff), IMREAD_COLOR);

Comment: imshow("the client itself screen", imgMat);
  waitKey(1);

Comment: In the same client program, I then make the image in this buffer appear with imshow(), which proves that the date is correct.

Comment: How to you read image in client? Show the code.

Comment: *How can I send vector<uchar> via socket?* -- Again, there is nothing wrong with the code you are showing.  A `vector` is simply a class that wraps a dynamic array.  The `data()` function gives you the data that is being wrapped, and the `size()` is the number of elements.  If you used `new[]` and `delete[]` instead of `vector`, you would have had the same issue.

Comment: In the client program I have this:

`int bytes = 0;

std::vector<uchar> buff;  //buffer for coding
   

if ((bytes = recv(client, (char*)buff.data(), sizeof(buff.data()), MSG_WAITALL)) == -1)
 `{
  cout << "Error while recv frame" << endl;
  break;
 `}

cv::Mat imgMat = cv::imdecode(Mat(buff), IMREAD_COLOR);
  
cv::imshow("Client screen seen from the Server", imgMat);
cv::waitKey(1);`

Comment: First, please edit your question with the new code.  Second, why are you using `sizeof(buff.data())`?  The `sizeof` does *not* give you the number of elements.  Is that a typo?  Shouldn't that be `buff.size()`?  And with that, where is the vector actually sized to the number of elements.  The code you posted in the comments doesn't show the vector being sized -- instead it shows usage of an empty vector.

Comment: Side note: `::cout << "Frame sent sucessfuly" << endl;` lies. If the socket represents a TCP connection, you cannot claIm to have sent the frame until after you have confirmed that `bytes` equals `buff.size()` or  continued sending more of the frame until the enough bytes for whole frame have been sent. If it's a UDP connection... Well, there's no way to be sure of much of anything with UDP.

Comment: I already changed it to buff.size() and gives zero, I thing a have to send its buffer size along with its actual buffer.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment, you say that you are passing `sizeof(buff.data())` to `recv()`.  This is wrong, you are specifying the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the data that it is pointing at. You need to use `buff.size()` instead.

As such, you need to pre-size `buff` before you can use it with `recv()`. Which means you need to know how many bytes to expect from the sender.  So the sender should send its buffer size along with its actual buffer data.

Try something more like this:

sender:

```
bool sendall(SOCKET sock, const void *data, uint32_t size)
{
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(data);
    while (size > 0)
    {
        int bytes = send(sock, ptr, static_cast<int>(size), 0);
        if (bytes < 0) return false;
        ptr += bytes;
        size -= bytes;
    }
    return true;
}

...

std::vector<uchar> buff;
std::vector<int> param(2);
param[0] = cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
param[1] = 40;//default(95) 0-100

if (!cv::imencode(".jpeg", frame, buff, param))
{
    std::cout << "Error encoding frame" << std::endl;
    break;
}

uint32_t size = buff.size();
if (!(sendall(server, &size, sizeof(size)) &&
      sendall(server, buff.data(), size)))
{
    std::cout << "Error sending frame" << std::endl;
    break;
}

std::cout << "Frame sent successfully" << std::endl;
std::cout << size << " bytes sent" << std::endl;
```

Receiver:

```
bool recvall(SOCKET sock, void *data, uint32_t size)
{
    return (recv(sock, static_cast<char*>(data), static_cast<int>(size), MSG_WAITALL) > 0);
}

...

uint32_t size;
if (!recvall(client, &size, sizeof(size)))
{
    std::cout << "Error while receiving frame" << std::endl;
    break;
}

std::vector<uchar> buff(size);
if (!recvall(client, buff.data(), size))
{
    std::cout << "Error while receiving frame" << std::endl;
    break;
}

cv::Mat imgMat = cv::imdecode(Mat(buff), IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::imshow("Client screen seen from the Server", imgMat);
cv::waitKey(1);
```

Alternatively, if your code runs on a platform that doesn't support `MSG_WAITALL`:

```
bool recvall(SOCKET sock, void *data, uint32_t size)
{
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(data);
    while (size > 0)
    {
        int bytes = recv(sock, ptr, static_cast<int>(size), 0);
        if (bytes <= 0) return false;
        ptr += bytes;
        size -= bytes;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

It worked.
You are a programming veteran.

I am very grateful to you.

And amazed that it worked. HEHE thank you a thousand

Comment: Now that it's working.

The image compression time for jpg varies between 20 milliseconds and 35 milliseconds. Is there any way to reduce this time to 10 milliseconds?

Comment: @JoãoCarlosDantasLopes That is a completely new and unrelated question that needs to be asked in its own post

Comment: oh! that `sizeof(buff.data())` was only revealed in a comment! nobody could have guessed that issue from the question.